Using slices of a Vec in a tokio task generates confusing errors
I have a Polars dataframe which I have processed into a Vec of columnar data of type Option<&str>. I want to send this to a database, but there are tens of thousands of rows, and I'm getting SQL "long transaction" warnings. To address these, I want to spread the work across multiple db connections. So I've created a tokio::JoinSet and spawn a bunch of tasks to do the SQL queries. To keep track of the indexes in each chunk, I'm using the very handy paginate crate.
I followed this answer to try to get this working, which recommends wrapping my Vecs in Arc since I don't need to modify the data. Unfortunately, I haven't succeeded yet.
Update I have created a CodeSandbox showing the issue I'm facing.
Update 2 I have fully aligned the code in this question, the error messages, and the CodeSandbox. Still looking for an answer to error #1.

use anyhow::Result;
use paginate::{Page, Pages};
use polars::prelude::*;
use rand::Rng;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::task::JoinSet;
const CONNECTION_COUNT: usize = 14;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let values: Vec<String> = (0..76_000)
        .map(|_| rng.gen_range(0..1000).to_string())
        .collect();
    let rand_df = df!("A" => values).unwrap();

    load_resources("NUMS", &rand_df);

    Ok(())
}

async fn load_resources(source_str: &str, in_df: &DataFrame) -> Result<()> {
    let merged_df = in_df.clone();

    // Error #1 is here ↴ -- see below
    let ids: Arc<Vec<_>> = Arc::new(merged_df.column("A")?.str()?.iter().collect());

    let count = in_df.shape().0;
    let pages = Pages::new(count, 5_000);
    let mut join_set = JoinSet::new();
    let mut results = Vec::new();

    for page in pages.into_iter() {
        join_set.spawn(async move {
            insert_resources(
                source_str,
                page,
                ids.clone(), // Error #2, see below
            )
            .await
        });

        if join_set.len() >= CONNECTION_COUNT {
            if let Some(result) = join_set.join_next().await {
                results.push(result.unwrap());
            }
        }
    }

    // Await the completion of all tasks
    while let Some(result) = join_set.join_next().await {
        results.push(result.unwrap());
    }

    Ok(())
}

async fn insert_resources(
    source_str: &str, // Error #3, see below
    page: Page,
    ids: Arc<Vec<Option<&str>>>,
) -> Result<()> {
    println!("source: {} page: {:?} names: {:?}", source_str, page, ids);

    Ok(())
}

The errors still say that my borrowed value doesn't live long enough, despite the fact that I'm cloning the DataFrame (after wrapping it in an Arc).
1. merged_df does not live long enough
error[E0597]: `merged_df` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:26:37
   |
23 |     let merged_df = in_df.clone();
   |         --------- binding `merged_df` declared here
...
26 |     let ids: Arc<Vec<_>> = Arc::new(merged_df.column("A")?.str()?.iter().co...
   |                                     ^^^^^^^^^---------------------------
   |                                     |
   |                                     borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                                     argument requires that `merged_df` is borrowed for `'static`
...
56 | }
   | - `merged_df` dropped here while still borrowed

2. use of moved value: names. And what's with that bizarre suggestion of putting .clone() after the async move block?? I tried it, and it doesn't compile.
error[E0382]: use of moved value: `ids`
  --> src/main.rs:34:24
   |
26 |       let ids: Arc<Vec<_>> = Arc::new(merged_df.column("A")?.str()?.iter...
   |           --- move occurs because `ids` has type `Arc<Vec<Option<&str>>>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
...
33 |       for page in pages.into_iter() {
   |       ----------------------------- inside of this loop
34 |           join_set.spawn(async move {
   |  ________________________^
35 | |             insert_resources(
36 | |                 source_str,
37 | |                 page,
38 | |                 ids.clone(), // Error #2, see below
   | |                 --- use occurs due to use in coroutine
39 | |             )
40 | |             .await
41 | |         });
   | |_________^ value moved here, in previous iteration of loop
   |
help: clone the value to increment its reference count
   |
41 |         }.clone());
   |          ++++++++

3. borrowed data escapes outside of function
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
  --> src/main.rs:34:9
   |
22 |   async fn load_resources(source_str: &str, in_df: &DataFrame) -> Result...
   |                           ----------  - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
   |                           |
   |                           `source_str` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
...
34 | /         join_set.spawn(async move {
35 | |             insert_resources(
36 | |                 source_str,
37 | |                 page,
...  |
40 | |             .await
41 | |         });
   | |          ^
   | |          |
   | |__________`source_str` escapes the function body here
   |            argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`

What is the right way to do this?

Your code says let merged_df = in_df.clone();, your error says let merged_df = db_eds_df. What to believe?

I dramatically simplified the code to try to focus the question, but left the errors as-is to avoid disrupting the ASCII art. merged_df is indeed created within the function, by joining other dfs together which are passed in, but in my real code none of them are called in_df. For the purposes of puzzling this out, in_df is correct. I hope that makes sense?

@Nickk9 if your example is a [mre] then you can just produce the errors from it, if not, then you should make it a MRE.

OK, I've simplified this further and created a CodeSandbox VM which is showing most of the errors.

Your post is still not coherent, the errors here don't match the code you've added here, note, for several reasons code that's on external resources only is not sufficient as a [mre] for a [so] question.

When you do async move { ... x.clone() ... }, it is the value x which is moved into the future. If x is a reference, this means that the closure must be known to live longer than the reference, which is untrue here. This is true regardless of whether you move the ref into the closure, because refs are Copy anyways. The compiler suggestion of using clone is correct, however, you need to clone BEFORE moving in the closure, for example let c = x.clone(); async move { ... c ... }

Furthermore I think that async { func(...).await } is probably an antipattern, perhaps there are exceptional cases where its necessary but you can write that as simple func(...). Inline async blocks are for where you want to do some non trivial composition of multiple other futures and functions inside the async block.

Super helpful, thank you! I've got 2 of the 3 issues resolved with your suggestions. (I've had to use Arc for the source_str as well.) Still stuck on the first error, though. "merged_df does not live long enough." CodeSandbox tweaked to show it… do I have to put that DF behind an Arc as well somehow? Very happy to accept an answer, if you'd like to write one.

Thanks very much to @user2407038 for helping clarify the issues.
To answer the questions about specific errors:

merged_df does not live long enough. The solution here was to transform the contents of the Vec to owned Strings instead of just &strs. This is achieved with: .map(|opt_str| opt_str.map(|s| s.to_string()))
use of moved value: ids. I took away the async move {}.await wrapper, so the clone() works well.
borrowed data escapes outside of function. Much like 1, I used an Arc to wrap a String when passing it into the function.

Full, compiling code here:
use anyhow::Result;
use paginate::{Page, Pages};
use polars::prelude::*;
use rand::Rng;
use std::sync::Arc;
use tokio::task::JoinSet;
const CONNECTION_COUNT: usize = 14;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let values: Vec<String> = (0..76_000)
        .map(|_| rng.gen_range(0..1000).to_string())
        .collect();
    let rand_df = df!("A" => values).unwrap();

    let _ = load_resources("NUMS", &rand_df);

    Ok(())
}

async fn load_resources(source_str: &str, in_df: &DataFrame) -> Result<()> {
    let merged_df = in_df.clone();

    let ids: Arc<Vec<_>> = Arc::new(
        merged_df
            .column("A")?
            .str()?
            .iter()
            .map(|opt_str| opt_str.map(|s| s.to_string()))
            .collect(),
    );
    let source = Arc::new(source_str.to_string());

    let count = in_df.shape().0;
    let pages = Pages::new(count, 5_000);
    let mut join_set = JoinSet::new();
    let mut results = Vec::new();

    for page in pages.into_iter() {
        join_set.spawn(insert_resources(source.clone(), page, ids.clone()));

        if join_set.len() >= CONNECTION_COUNT {
            if let Some(result) = join_set.join_next().await {
                results.push(result.unwrap());
            }
        }
    }

    // Await the completion of all tasks
    while let Some(result) = join_set.join_next().await {
        results.push(result.unwrap());
    }

    Ok(())
}

async fn insert_resources(
    source_str: Arc<String>,
    page: Page,
    ids: Arc<Vec<Option<String>>>,
) -> Result<()> {
    println!("source: {} page: {:?} names: {:?}", source_str, page, ids);

    Ok(())
}

